# Left and Right audio channels are exchanging

Tags: c, linux, audio, device-driver

I am trying to write an application for capturing stereo audio. My audio input has two channels(Stereo). I am writing this audio data into a wav file. Some times these audio channels are exchanging i.e, Left becomes right and right becomes left. This is happening only if i open and close the device file or turn off the device and turn it on. And it is happening randomly. I don't want channels to be exchanged. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stereo PCM stored in a wav file is in an LR format. 'L' stands for left channel sample and 'R' for right channel sample. I guess you have a bug in retrieving or storing the PCM. Maybe sometimes you start with the right (correct) position in buffer and sometimes you start with the second sample. It's hard to tell without additional info.